# What is the difference between the following queries

Tags: sql

[I have seen this question from sql zoo select from world tutorial(13 th one)](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQLZOO:SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial)

```
SELECT 
    name, continent,
    CASE 
       WHEN continent = 'Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
       WHEN continent = 'Eurasia' OR name = 'Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
       WHEN continent = 'Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'b%' THEN 'North America'
       WHEN continent = 'Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'b%' THEN 'South America'
       ELSE continent 
    END
FROM world
ORDER BY name;

SELECT
    name, continent AS 'Original Continent',
    CASE WHEN continent = 'Oceania' THEN 'Australasia' 
         WHEN continent = 'Eurasia' OR name = 'Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
         WHEN continent IN (SELECT continent FROM world 
                            WHERE continent = 'Caribbean' 
                              AND name LIKE 'B%') THEN 'North America' 
         WHEN continent IN (SELECT continent FROM world 
                            WHERE continent = 'Caribbean' 
                              AND name NOT LIKE 'B%') THEN 'South America'  
         ELSE continent 
    END as 'New Continent'     
FROM  
    world 
ORDER BY
    name;
```

the first one shows the right results and the second didn't what is the difference? Can any one please answer.

Comment: OI removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Check table data, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
WHEN continent IN (SELECT continent 
                    FROM world 
                    WHERE continent = 'Caribbean' 
                    AND name LIKE 'B%') THEN 'North America'
```

You are assigning all countries in the Carribean with `North America`, since your `IN` part:

```
(SELECT continent FROM world WHERE continent = 'Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%')
```

will return

```
continent
-------------
Caribbean
Caribbean
Caribbean
```

You essentially have

```
 WHEN continent IN ('Caribbean') THEN 'North America'
```

Which is not correct, since it won't assign any of the countries to the continent of South America. Using a subquery version you would need to use `name` rather than `continent`:

```
WHEN name IN (SELECT name FROM world WHERE continent = 'Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%')
    THEN 'North America' 
WHEN name IN (SELECT name FROM world WHERE continent = 'Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%') 
    THEN 'South America'
```